# How to determine ratios for mean-reverting basket

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, statistics, trading, regression, cointegration

Suppose I have a basket of 3 securities A, B, and C. I believe that the basket is cointegrated and I want to create a mean-reverting trade. I fit the model:
$\log(A)=\beta_b*\log(B)+\beta_c*\log(C)+\alpha$ where A, B, and C are the prices of the securities.

This gives me estimates of $\alpha$, $\beta_b$ and $\beta_c$.

Now suppose that I believe that the spread is out of line. I want to sell \$1 of A and buy \$1 of the B and C basket. How should I allocate that dollar to B and C? Is it simply $\beta_b*\$1$ units of B and $\beta_c*\$1$ units of C or is it more complex?

Related, is it more correct to regress log prices or raw prices when fitting the model?

(I know that this is related to [How to build a mean reverting basket?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/how-to-build-a-mean-reverting-basket) but the answers there weren't very detailed and this is a more specific question).

Comment: You generally regress returns, not prices...

Comment: The classic pairs trading paper Gatev & Goetzmann 2006 regresses prices

Comment: Can get it out with a mass simulation if you can't figure it out.

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21994/pairs-trading-signals-and-positioning/24818#24818

Answer (score 2):

In a recent paper - [Cointegration and Relative Value Arbitrage](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2785045) by Binh Do and Robert Faff, the issue of relative value arbitrage with three stocks is addressed. On page 27 they formulate the cointegrating relation similarly to how you did: $$\ p_{1t} = \alpha + \gamma p_{2t} + \beta p_{3t} + \epsilon_t$$

They also say that the dollar weights of the asset should satisfy the following equations:

$$ w_1/w_2 = p_{1t}/-\gamma p_{2t} $$
$$ w_1/w_3 = p_{1t}/-\beta p_{3t} $$
$$ |w_1| + |w_2| + |w_3| = 2 $$

Hope this helps.